# Dialog in full Screen

Tags: android, android-dialog

My question is i don't want to show transparent dialog in full screen 
below is the code i used

```
 dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enterjoinseecode_dialog);
```

CustomDialog theme

```
  <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

Please some one helps me where i went wrong

Comment: Can you please post the `error or unwanted behaviour` you are getting by running your code??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Create your view for `Dialog` like below.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

// Here you can add your component.

</RelativeLayout>
```

And set your dialog this view.

```
 dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enterjoinseecode_dialog);
```

That's it.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a activity with transparent background and for that particular activity define theme like this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

And also if you want that activity to be exactly like dialog, then you can also use this

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to remove it from the recent apps list.

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to show that in only dialog. Not in activity

Comment: If you use this, then your activity will be like a dialog. Just try and see. It would be exactly the same as dialog.

Comment: thanks for your comments . but don't want to add all events related to dialog in separate activity.

Comment: Could you tell what all dialog events do you have that you are unwilling to move?

Answer (score 0):

some how with the following steps got the dialog with transparent effect with out full screen

No need of defining style "CustomDialogTheme" need to pass the theme argument for constructor as android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar

and with in inflated xml just used background as android:background="#29000000" to make it transparent effect and layout_gravity property to position the dialog

if i use the above style CustomDialogTheme somehow its showing as a window instead of dialog because of that i applied direct theme to show that as dialog (not full screen)and to make it transparent effect with in xml i set the property background